# Copy file even when destination exists (in Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, file-copying

In the [QFile::copy](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfile.html#copy-2) documentation it says

> If a file with the name newName already exists, copy() returns false
>   (i.e., QFile will not overwrite it).

But I need to copy a file even if the destination exists. Any workaround available in Qt for that?

Deleting the file is the obvious solution but it invites a race condition...

Comment: [`QFile::remove`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfile.html#remove-2)?

Comment: Qt really likes to make your life hard sometimes.. they could simply add a third optional parameter to overwrite files but no..

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
if (QFile::exists("/home/user/dst.txt"))
{
    QFile::remove("/home/user/dst.txt");
}

QFile::copy("/home/user/src.txt", "/home/user/dst.txt");
```

Comment: Solution isn't atomic.

Answer (score 17):

The obvious solution is of course to delete the file if it exists, before doing the copy.

Note however that doing so opens up the code to a classic [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition), since on a typical multitasking operating system a different process could re-create the file *between* your applications' delete and copy calls. That would cause the copy to still fail, so you need to be prepared (and perhaps re-try the delete, but that might introduce a need for count so you don't spend forever attempting, and on and on).

Comment: This answer is correct - but there's some irony here. [The actual code for `QFile::copy()` itself](https://github.com/radekp/qt/blob/6f5fb0be85b1d7cc9f93b615b5034c882e946301/src/corelib/io/qfile.cpp#L848) has a race condition.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest retrying I can think of is:

```
while !QFile::copy("/home/user/src.txt", "/home/user/dst.txt")
{
    QFile::remove("/home/user/dst.txt");
}
```

But this still isn't a real solution as some of the race conditions are things that don't block remove.

I'm currently hunting for a way to handle writing a web page as an output but without the auto refresh ever catching between the remove and the copy.

Comment: Imagine you don't have file-permissions to do copy/remove. Now you have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 4):

Just call `remove()` before  calling `copy()`